# Auto relative symbolic links in Mac OS X

Tags: terminal, symlink

I wanna ask if it is possible to **automatically** create relative symbolic links in Mac OS X ?

Seems like Linux has -r option for ln to do this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10370/make-a-symbolic-link-to-a-relative-pathname.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html

But alas, it is not the option for Mac OS X:
https://ss64.com/osx/ln.html

I've found here similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317809/how-to-create-relative-symbolic-link-in-mac-os.
but it's about manual relative link calculation instead of automatic like -r option for ln do in Linux.

So my question - is there any option in Mac OS X to make relative symlinks automatically instead of absolute ones? My shell is Bash, not zsh, system is macOS 10.15.7 Catalina, if it matters.

Thanks in advance!
PS: Sorry for my English - it isn't my native language...

Comment: This question might be easier to understand and better received by the community if you add the relevant details directly in the question itself. How should the link look like, what do you currently get when just using `ln -s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU version of `ln` can be installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). It is part of the `coreutils` package (`brew install coreutils`) and can then be called as `gln` (to avoid conflicts with the macOS versions).